# Using old web application with outdated PHP version behind .htaccess folder protection

Tags: php, security, lamp

I probably need a web server with an outdated PHP Version (7.2.34) for an older HTML/PHP/MySQL based web application. Since it's for a manageable closed user group, I exceptionally considered using a mandatory .htaccess folder protection for the application. As a result there would be no public access to the application. Public/direct access to the databaseserver will also not be possible. If the Webserver would still receives updates, the attack surface might be an containable risk for us. Due to extensive changes to the code base of the web application and no longer maintained PlugIns, updating the application is no solution. So the goal is to keep the application running as long as possible with a containable risk.

I already managed classic vServer for webhosting projects, but never with an outdated software component. Regarding Debian 11 for example I read about installing PHP 7.2 with SURY repository, but there also might be solutions for other distributions like Ubuntu server or CentOS.

Is it possible to use PHP 7.2.34 in combination with still maintained Webserver and Database, or at least with maintained Webserver? If possible, which distribution would offer the longest support for the Webserver?

Answer (score 0):

If changing the distribution is an option, you might consider using REL8 or a distribution based on it. The PHP version that comes on the system is 7.2.24 and Red Hat will provide security updates for the lifetime of the OS (somewhere in 2029).

Alternatives to REL include Rocky Linux and Oracle Enterprise Linux. AlmaLinux is another alternative but I'm not as familiar with that distribution.